# Is the map between mapping spaces, induced by the functor $\vert Sing(-)\vert$ continuous?

Tags: gn.general-topology, simplicial-stuff

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Let $\vert Sing(-)\vert$ be the functor which sends a topological space to the (or "a"? there seem to be more possibilites, for me it's just important, that I get CW complexes at the end) geometric realization of the singular set of the space.

Is the map $C(X,Y)\rightarrow C(\vert Sing(X)\vert,\vert Sing(Y)\vert)$ we get (as $\vert Sing(-)\vert$ is a functor) continuous in the compact-open topology?

Comment: $|Sing(-)|$ is not even well-defined. If you pick the realizations arbitrarily, how do you extend it to a functor?

Comment: @Wojowu: The geometric realization functor is left adjoint to Sing, therefore it is well-defined.

Answer (score 4):

This map is not continuous except in some degenerate cases. Take $X = *$ and $Y = [0, 1]$ so that the map reduces to $[0, 1] \to |\mathrm{Sing} [0, 1]|$. Its image is the discrete set of vertices, in particular it is disconnected, so the map is discontinuous.